# Not able to click Button(element) on Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[image]Not able to click Button(element) on Selenium webdriver. It's showing no such element exception.

HTML:

```
<button id="datepicker-354-7412-title" class="btn btn-default btn-sm uib-title" tabindex="-1" ng-disabled="datepickerMode === maxMode" ng-click="toggleMode()" type="button" aria-atomic="true" aria-live="assertive" role="heading">
    <strong class="ng-binding">August 2016</strong>
</button>
```

Java:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='flip-card']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/i")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(05, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='uib-datepicker-popup dropdown-menu ng-scope']/li/div/table/thead/tr/th/button[@id='datepicker-758-2620-title']/strong")).click();
//driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='datepicker-961-3767-title']")).click();
//WebElement mm=driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker-1164-5186-title"));
//mm.click();
/*WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='datepicker-354-7412-title']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element); */
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='datepicker-354-7412-title']/strong")).click();
```

Comment: <button id="datepicker-354-7412-title" class="btn btn-default btn-sm uib-title" tabindex="-1" ng-disabled="datepickerMode === maxMode" ng-click="toggleMode()" type="button" aria-atomic="true" aria-live="assertive" role="heading">
<strong class="ng-binding">August 2016</strong>
</button>

Comment: show your click Button code.

Comment: Please add the html and your Java code to the question.

Comment: <button id="datepicker-354-7412-title" class="btn btn-default btn-sm uib-title" tabindex="-1" ng-disabled="datepickerMode === maxMode" ng-click="toggleMode()" type="button" aria-atomic="true" aria-live="assertive" role="heading">
<strong class="ng-binding">August 2016</strong>
</button>    @Guy

Comment: could you show your code of clicking button?

Comment: @boopathi You already posted the html in the comments. It should be added to the question (as someone already did). You should add your Java code as well.

Comment: Is the button inside `<frame>` or `<iframe>` tag?

Comment: there is no frame @Guy

Comment: Why would you find the element by XPath while it has an id?

Comment: i tried with everything @Thibstars  ...org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='datepicker-354-161-title']"}
Command duration or timeout: 5.13 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id might be dynamic, try to locate the button by partial id that contains `datepicker` and `title`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id*='datepicker'][id*='title']")).click();
```

You can also use explicit wait to make sure the button exist/visible before clicking on it

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

// visible
WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[id*='datepicker'][id*='title']")));
button.click();

// or exist
WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[id*='datepicker'][id*='title']")));
button.click();
```

Comment: @boopathi Check again the html for `<frame>` or `<iframe>` tags. This is the only other explanation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122103/discussion-between-boopathi-and-guy).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker-354-7412-title")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your xpath in firepath and checking if its pointing to what you want?

have you tried using

//strong[@class='ng-binding'] as your xpath?

let know if this helps?

Comment: its working with this code           driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id*='datepicker'][id*='title']")).click();

Answer (score 0):

Find xpath using firefox addon firebug:
- inspect element
- right click on element and copy xpath

Firebug's xpath generator is really good and the path generated generally works on other browsers.

Hope that helps.