# not able to click Button element in Geb/Groovy

Tags: button, groovy, click, geb

Very similar to [Not able to click Button(element) on Selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204417/not-able-to-click-buttonelement-on-selenium-webdriver)

The button is defined in the web page as:

```
<button class="gigantic-long-string-gwtui-etc" 
type="button" style="width: 60px" tabIndex="200">OK</button>
```

I'm using Geb. I defined the button as follows:

```
systemUseNotification (wait:true) { $("button", text:"OK") }
```

and tried to click the button with:

```
waitFor(60) {systemUseNotification.click()}
```

The code was able to find the button, but click() never worked.  I had to use a strange work-around sending the ENTER key to the button

```
systemUseNotification << Keys.chord(Keys.ENTER))
```

The other control that the code could find but not click was defined by

```
templateTab(wait:true) { $("td" , text:"Templates")}
```

This is a table cell that changes the view when you click on it.
Again, calling click() on this templateTab did not do anything.  This is even with `waitFor` wrapped around it, and verifying the code found the control.

The actual definition in the HTML is `<td class="main-menu-item-text">Templates<td>`

What *did* work was `$(class:'main-menu-item-text', text:"Templates").click()`

But I really do not like having to specify the class name as it defeats the purpose of having change-resistant test code.

Same question where I am trying to click a div control button defined as

I want to call use something like:
`$("div", title:"Switch Dashboards").click()`
But this does not work either.
Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I used this snippet of code to try and test your issue, but my code worked. can you give this a try:
`go("http://www.google.com")` and then call: `waitFor {$(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gb_70\"]")).click()}`

Comment: I also assume that the test code passes? If it does not what does the stack trace say?

Comment: @switch201 - I had to use a variation of this, `waitFor{$(By.xpath("//*@value='Search']")).click()}`.  Got  a MissingMethodException.  I'll try to copy as much of the stack trace as possible; it's on a network not accessible to the Internet.
`No signature of method: geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.$() is applicable for argument types: (org....By$ByXPath) values: [By.xpath //*[@value='Search']]

Comment: @switch201 - I think my original code is in fact working!
I think one problem was that I had a load of `println` debug statements inside the `waitFor` block, which caused it to fail.

Comment: At least some of it was.

I get the `StaleElementReferenceException` when I try to perform a `click()` for the `templateTab` in the code above.

So `systemUseNotification` works fine. Just not the `templateTab`.

Comment: When you get a StaleElementReferenceException, that means the DOM has been changed or reloaded between when you defined your Navigator object and when you call click(). you can fix it by adding a try catch or you can define and execute your click in the same line of code.

Comment: Also in the varation you posted earlier you are missing "[" in your xpath it should say: `waitFor{$(By.xpath("//*[@value='Search']")).click()}`

Comment: @switch201 - So I tried what you suggested, but it only works when I specify the class, which I rather would not do. 
`waitFor {$("td.main-menu-item-text", text:"Templates").click()} // works
`waitFor {$("td", text:"Templates").click()} // does not work - stale


(I should move this to a chat, but I don't have enough rep yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following technique worked:

```
waitFor {$("td", class:contains("text"), text:"Templates").click()}
```

I still prefer to avoid having to know anything about the class, though, but at least this reduced the size of the string I have to match.

I tried, for example `class:contains(~/.*/)` and `class:~/.*/` so I could be "class-agnostic", but those always resulted in stale.